# solve $\lim_{n \to \infty}\left( \frac{3+2n}{\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2}n} + i\,n\right)$

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, problem-solving

I am checking this sequence for convergence but i am not sure whether i am on the right path in calculations, these steps are what i am doing now. $\infty + n$ will go to infinity, right?

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{3+2n}{\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2}n} + i\,n = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{3+2n}{\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2}n} + \lim_{n \to \infty}i\,n = \sqrt{2} + \infty = \infty$$

am i okay? can someone please correct me if i am wrong. many thanks for any guidance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $i$ the imaginary unit then the sequece diverges in modulus.

That sequence will diverge in any case if $i\not = -\sqrt{2}$ is a constant and does not depend on $n$

Comment: why it doesnot depend on $n$, i dont get the point

Comment: you're right, I should start avoiding this kind of words, they do not carry any positive contribution and can lead to awkward moments!

Comment: @doniyor You did not give any information about what $i$ is. In principle it could be something like $-n$ or $-e^n$!

Comment: ok then if $i$ is the imaginary unit the sequence diverges in modulus as you said!

Comment: it means that the sequence of the absolute values of the terms of your sequence goes to +infinity!

Comment: okay, fine! :) Thanks dude. great help!